# Archiving directory tree preserving permissions in Windows

Tags: windows, permissions, acl

I have to archive (= move to an "archive" subfolder and set the read-only flag) a set of remote directories, preserving the ACLs, on a remote Windows server. The directories have different access right, some inherited from the parent folder, some not. It is fundamental that the moved directories preserve their access permissions (for instance, some directories might be accessible only by the managers and have to remain so).

I have played a bit with the "Read only" flag in the directories' properties and it seems to partially meet my requirements -- after I set it, I am still able to create a new file in the RO directory, and I would like to prevent it.

The biggest problem is, however, in moving the directories without destroying the ACLs.

Can anyone help me with the above mentioned issues, please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to first back up the current ACLs using `icacls /save`, so that in case of problems you'll be able to just `icacls /restore` and restart from beginning.

---

Permissions are inherited (or re(-re(-re…))inherited) only from the immediate parent directory, not from all parents together. So it should be enough to disable inheritance for the topmost directory itself (making the permissions static), e.g. using

```
icacls my_2008_project /inheritance:d
```

This will convert the currently inherited ACEs into static ones, so the resulting ACL won't change no matter where the directory is moved – and therefore ACLs inherited by its files and subdirectories won't change either.

*(Actually, merely moving items [wouldn't automatically adjust inherited permissions anyway](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060824-16/?p=29973), but the above step makes sure that won't happen by accident either.)*

---

To prevent writing, you'll have to use ACLs as well. (The "read-only" attribute only works with files – it's completely ignored for directories.) Easiest would be to add a 'deny' ACE:

```
icacls my_2008_project /t /deny Everyone:W
```

This will add the ACE individually to each item (since you mentioned that some of them have inheritable permissions disabled).

A regular inheritable version would be:

```
icacls my_2008_project /deny Everyone:(OI)(CI)W
```